# Compatible libraries for Azure Cosmos GraphDB and Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I am trying to offload data from Azure-Databricks onto Azure Cosmos-GraphDB as needed vertices and edges.

I am continuously encountering **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException** error. I have mostly tried all my cards with all combinations of Library versions and respective Databricks Runtime Versions, but no luck. I have tried most of the compatible library versions mentioned under - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos-spark_3-2_2-12/README.md#download

I will be using **DBR- 10.4 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.2.1, Scala 2.12)**, so any guidance on the right MAVEN libraries for Azure Cosmos Graph DB, please?

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.
Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
```

Comment: That SDK explicitly states it's for the SQL API of Cosmos DB. You can't use it to write via Graph API. You'd need to use a gremlin-specific sdk.

Comment: Have you seen this article: [Connect Azure Databricks to CosmosDB Gremlin API and run queries](https://medium.com/azure-tutorials/connect-azure-databricks-to-cosmosdb-gremlin-api-and-run-queries-f2c29522a72f) ?

Comment: @Thomas - Yes. I used Gremlin-python SDK and it works. But I'm looking for spark-connectors for Azure databricks, So that I can work with data frames directly.  eg:

df.write.format("com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark").options(**writeConfig).save()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below library with Graphframes did the trick. I am able to ingest data into azure cosmos-DB,  even quicker than gremlin-python.

```
com.azure.cosmos.spark:azure-cosmos-spark_3-2_2-12:4.11.1
```

I had to engage **cosmos.oltp** SQL API along with the above library.

```
cosmos_edges.write.format("cosmos.oltp").options(**cfg).mode("APPEND").save()
```